# Google play signs apk with legacy signing key, not new key

Tags: android, google-play

I have an application uploaded to my site and it has lots of installs.
I uploaded my app to playstore 2 years ago, but app rejected due to some issues.
Now i uploaded my app new version and google play accepted to publish.
but i have an issue:

I changed my signing key in play console, i can see new SHA-1 & SHA-256 for my new signing key.

Then I uploaded a new bundle in console, then i checked App bundle explorer in console and downloaded Universal apk and checked it signing key, but google signed it with legacy key, not new key.

I uploaded a new version of my app with new version code, but again it signed with legacy key.

What should i do?

---

***ANSWER:***

After a few days of research it turns out there is an option when you want to upload new signing key to select this key should use Android T and above or all android versions, which i checked wrong. so ic contacted google support hoping they change this option.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ethry there is no code, i have a problem with play console.

Comment: @mohammadaghili Did you find any solution after contacting google. We have a similar issue and are stuck with it. The issue is raised with google but they have not provided any solution yet.

Comment: Same issue for me, I download apk from Bundle explorer, it still use legacy signer

Comment: Did you figure out how to obtain the apk signed with the new key? I'm experienced the same issue, and contacted the Google support. They basically said that the legacy key will still be used also for new installs on Android T and the will be replaced with the new one using key rotation feature (introduced in signature v3) upon app update. But still it's not clear to me how I can test with an apk signed with the new key. Any apk downloaded from the play console is signed with the legacy key.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you understand Google Play Signing.  With Google Play Signing, you sign with key A.  That proves you wrote the APK.  You upload the apk signed with key A.  Google then takes that apk and resigns it with key B.  That's the apk that's downloaded.  This is how it has to work-  this is why you can change key A-  because the actual key that's downloaded to all the devices is B, and that will never change (if it did change, the installer would throw an error because that's a security issue.  Keys can't change once installed).

So this is working as expected.  Changing your key won't change the key used when you download it.  It will just change the key used to upload it.  This was protection because in the old days there was only a single key, and people lost it.  Now with Google Play Signing, Google keeps the actual key for you so you can't lose it (and if you lose Key A, you can replace it easily).

Comment: Thanks for your response, do you mean upload key by key A & signing key by key B?
if so, I used same key for both upload and signing keys & in play console panel shows the correct keys SHA1 and SHA256. Before changing signing key play console warned you can do this action once annually, and i accepted and my key successfully changed.
Now imagine my legacy signing key SHA1 ended with 01 and new one ended with 02.
google still signs it with 01 and not 02, but it shows 02 as signing key in App integrity section in play console. and thats exactly where i have problem

Comment: Google also said old install will sign with old signing key and new installs will sign with new signing key

Comment: @mohammadaghili No, they didn't say it at all.  You completely misunderstood.  That would never work, because the entire Android security model is based around the key NEVER changing on the downloaded APK.  It's impossible for it to change without requiring an uninstall and reinstall of the app with the new key.  The APK *uploaded to google* will have the new key.  The APK downloaded from Google will only ever have the key created by Google.

Comment: This is exactly what Google said for hint in my console panel:
You can upgrade your app signing key for new installs, for example if you want to move to a cryptographically stronger key. Google will use the new key to sign all new installs and their updates. Your legacy key will still be used to sign updates for users who already have your app installed. You can request a new key once per app, and this works for all Android API levels.

Comment: @mohammadaghili "Your legacy key will still be used for users who already have your app installed".  Unless you factory reset your phone and installed it on a new Google account that has never downloaded it, you are a user who already has the app installed.  So working as intended.

Comment: I uninstalled app and downloaded again from playstore and checked the sign of downloaded apk, it is still the legacy key.
I even downloaded it with new google account, and it still downloaded with legacy key.
I download Universal APK from "App bundle explorer" in google console and checked its sign, it signed with legacy key. I mean new signing key is never used with google, but it shows in my console as new signing key. (I can see two signing keys in my panel, one old, and one latest that i recently updated in google console, but new key is not used for signing any apks)

Comment: @mohammadaghili Uninstalling isn't sufficient.  Play knows at one point you downloaded it, so it serves the old key because it could be necessary (for example if it was uninstalled but the data was kept, it could also effect automated backup).  You'd always see the same key if the account has downloaded it before.   Factory reset and a fresh google account.

Comment: Is this includes installs from other sources? or only installs from playstore?
(downloads from other sources are signed with that key I uploaded to console as new signing key.)

Comment: even factory reset and creating new account on that device didn't work